# Django: "Form object has no attribute..." error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm new in Django ,and I'm trying to develop a simple Django application which takes two numbers from the user with a form and do some operation with those numbers and print the result with a Http Response. My code is the following:

forms.py

```
class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    a = forms.IntegerField(label='first' )
    b = forms.IntegerField(label='second' )

    def result(self):
        return doSomething(self.a, self.b)
```

views.py

```
class MainPage(FormView):
    template_name = 'simple.html'
    success_url = '/result/'
    form_class = SimpleForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return HttpResponse(form.result())
```

However, when I run this code on my localhost, it gives the error like

```
SimpleForm object has no attribute 'a'
```

So, what can be the problem? How can I get the user input in order to use it in my "result" function?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access data,  you need to use `form.data`:

```
def result(self):
    return doSomething(self.data['a'], self.data['b'])
```

If you called `form.is_valid()` before call `result`, you can also use `cleaned_data`. (Because OP is using `FormView.form_valid`, it is called automatically)

```
def result(self):
    return doSomething(self.cleaned_data['a'], self.cleaned_data['b'])
```

Comment: He call `result()` in `form_valid()`, so `form.is_valid()` was already call. Here it is preferable to only use `cleaned_data` to be sure about data verification, no?

Comment: @Wilfried, You're right. I missed that. I'll mention that. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What is the difference between self.data and self.cleaned_data? I mean which one should I prefer?

Comment: @qwerty, `self.data` returns raw data (strings), while `self.cleaned_data` returns converted data according to field type (int for the given case).

Answer (score 1):

You `form.a` is an `IntergerField()`, not the result. You need to read `cleaned_data` dict of your form to access value of your form field. [Cleaned_data documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)

```
class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    a = forms.IntegerField(label='first' )
    b = forms.IntegerField(label='second' )

    def result(self):
        return doSomething(self.cleaned_data['a'], self.cleaned_data['b'])
```